# Find the number of the job in parallel gnu-make

Tags: gnu-make

When running make with -j, is it possible to find the number of a running job?

For example with a Makefile like:

```
SUBDIRS = a b c

default: all

$(SUBDIRS)::
    $(MAKE) -C $@ $(MAKECMDGOALS)

all clean : $(SUBDIRS)
```

if I run `make -j4` can I echo some variable that is different for each job?

Is that number even available?

Answer (score 0):

Run `$ make` on this Makefile…

```
.PHONY: all clean

files := a b c

all: $(files)

$(files): clean
    @echo "Creating file: $@, Unique Job ID: $${$$}"
    @touch $@

clean:
    @rm -f $(files)
```

In this case, your unique job number is `$${$$}`. This is the Make equivalent of [Bash's `$$` Process ID Internal Variable](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html) since dollar signs must be escaped with a dollar sign. To further clarify, the a variable `$foo` or `${foo}` in Bash would be `$$foo` or `$${foo}` in Make, respectively.